# Macro doesnt running Excel 2007 second parameter

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I create a Public vba function with 2 parameters(module).
When I call the function I type **"=InvoiceAmount2(A9;B9)"**.
The first parameter turns blue. The second black.
I remake the same function using one parameter, the second I use into the function, that way it´s ok. But I need two parameters

Comment: What's the signature of the function? Can you post the Function() definition? (Not the whole function, just the first line).

Comment: Fix your calling syntax to =InvoiceAmount2(A9,B9). Use a comma instead of a semicolon. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: The use of `;` or `,` is dependant on the language version of Excel you are using.  @Andrew 's suggextion to try , and @Gary 's request for the function definition will help us provide an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how you call a user defined function with two parameters:

=MyFunction(A1,B1)

Sample Code:

```
Function MyFunction(rCellA As Range, rCellB As Range)

    MyFunction = rCellA.Value + rCellB.Value

End Function
```

Comment: The problem continue the same. I change the code but this do not function.

Comment: To @Gary -function signature: Function InvoiceAmount2(Product, Volume) End Function

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I call the udf function in formula constructor. I informed the parameters (A9 and B9)
finally, the udf function filled the cell. "=InvoiceAmount2(A9;B9)".